# GridView Blank On Pagination

Tags: sql, gridview

I have no problem getting a GridView or ListView to page, normally.  If I use Sql datasource and I use a query like:

```
SELECT RecipeName FROM PostedRecipes
```

and I enter Hot Dog, for example, in a search text box, and there are 40 Hot Dog recipes, the GridView/ListView will show page 1 with 10 recipes (if the count is set to 10) and show that there are 3 more pages to go.  Each page then, page 2 or 3 or 4, will show additional recipes. However,

If I use a query like:

```
SELECT RecipeName FROM PostedRecipes 
WHERE RecipeName LIKE '%' + @RecipeName + '%' GROUP BY RecipeName
```

and I make the same search entry, the GridView will show page 1 with 10 recipes and indicate that there are 3 more pages.  BUT, if I click on page 2 or 3 or 4, a blank page is then displayed.

If I set the count to 40, all 40 recipes will be displayed on the initial search - which would indicate that all the recipes are being retrieved from the database.  I am not sure if this is some sort of GridView problem or a postback problem of some sort.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Invariably the gridview is getting hung up getting the 2nd, 3rd & 4th sets of 10 recipes from the more complicated query. So instead of binding it to this gridsource, run the query and get the results to a datatable & bind the gridsource to the datatable instead.

Comment: John, thanks for the response.  I must be missing something with paging. If I set the page size to 40, all 40 recipes even with this query will display. Only when the page size is smaller and the page count comes into play do I have this problem.  Is the problem that the GridView must make a call back to the database when the 2nd page is clicked and it does know what to query so it returns blank?